# Preventing Edits to specific rows in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, datagridview

I want to prevent the user from editing or deleting the first three rows of a datagridview.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
private void dataGridView3_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e) {
    if (e.RowIndex < 3) {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}

private void dataGridView3_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Row.Index < 3) {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to capture _CellBeginEdit event, check if any edits on the targeted row are allowed, and cancel event if no edits allowed:

> private void dataGridViewIndexesSpecs_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
>           {

```
        if (e.RowIndex <= 3)
            e.Cancel = true;

    }
```

Comment: will that prevent them from deleting it too?